# SQL Server managed instance how to backup database to local file system

Tags: sql-server, blob, instance, managed

We utilize SQL Server as a managed SQL instance. All input and output files / data is to the blob. I need to perform a full backup of a database and store it on local file system and restore it later. Any suggestions

Via SSMS tried to use SQL Server database name / tasks / backup and was given no option for local file system only a USL. I also tried access to known blob storage container and it would not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

What about backing up database to blob storage as described in paragraph "Take a backup on SQL Managed Instance" of [Restore a database to SQL Server from Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/restore-database-to-sql-server?view=azuresql&tabs=managed-identity), and then download the file from the blob storage as described in [Download blobs from Azure Blob Storage by using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download)?

To restore follow [Upload files to Azure Blob storage by using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json) and the "Restore to SQL Server" paragraph of the first article.

You could create a powershell script to perform the backup operation and another one to restore it.

I don't think there is a single command to backup a managed databaes to local storage.